# How to clear cells if ISBLANK?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add clearing function. If "B1" is blank, then clear C1,D1,E1,F1;

But I don't know how I can do it. I tried custom function in formatting, but not works.
Can u help me?

[image]

Comment: It is unclear whether the values in columns `C:F` are manually entered, or generated by formulas. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219), and make sure you are not describing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: possible only with script

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
    let your_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/your_sheet_id').getSheetByName('Sheet1')
    let cell_check = your_sheet.getRange('B1');
    if(cell_check.isBlank()) {
        your_sheet.getRange('C1:F1').clearContent();
    }else{
      console.log('not empty')
    }
}
```

But I would probably advise considering the use of numbered ranges instead of named ranges as it will be easer to reason about at scale if you are running through multiple rows.

```
function myNumberedRangeFunction() {
    let your_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/your_sheet_id').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    let cell_check = your_sheet.getRange(1,2);
    /* getRange(
            1, the first row,
            2, is the second column
        )
    */
    if(cell_check.isBlank()) {
        your_sheet.getRange(1,3,1,4).clearContent();
        /* getRange(
            1, the first row,
            3, the third column,
            1, get one row, 
            4, get four columns
        )
    */
    }else{
      console.log('not empty')
    }
}
```

Typically, if I am manipulating a large spreadsheet, I will pull the entire spreadsheet `data_table = your_sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).isBlank() ? [] : Array.from(your_sheet.getRange(1,1,your_sheet.getLastRow(),your_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues());` and convert it to a table array that I can analyze and manipulate all at once and then just place the changes all at once with
`your_sheet.getRange(1,1,data_table.length,data_table[0].length).setValues(data_table)`

Answer (score 1):

You can *hide*, but not clear, the values in columns `C:F` with this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

`=isblank($B1)`

The rule should set the text color to match the cell fill color, making the value in the cell "invisible".